# Google in app after publishing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

**i have publised my application as well as id..i have downloaded application from application store on**

1..phone with id to purchase

2..another device with purchasing it

3..another device with test account

**now i cant purchase it and it is giving me following error**

1..phone with id to purchase-->this version of application is not configured for billing through google play

2..another device with purchasing iD-->iTEM NOT FOUND

3..another device with test account --->the item you request is not avaible for purchase

can any one plz help me..

Do google have to upgrade its server to allow inaap purchase

Comment: do you have sign apk in your device?

Comment: Mehul i have downloaded application from google play..and also google inapp is implemented in it...and surely google play accepts signed apk

Comment: Make sure the version codes are the same on both sides, the item ids as well(when you make the request).

Comment: dear thnks...but i am saying that i have downloaded from google play...i have not downloade from pc..do google play store take time to upgrade inapp id and inapp purchase..even after publishing application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After publishing application to the market. it take around **3 - 4 hours** or even more to get **uploaded** or get **updated**.

Make sure that you have make **item as published** when you added it in your application in google account.

And one more thing to note is that you can only purchase the item if you have **valid credit card** details for the gmail id that you are using for purchasing.

Comment: i have published my apk on 6 december and today is 7 december and still its giving "Item not found"

Comment: Have you published that item also? Have you used same product id and manage type in your code